# c++ lambda capture not supported in firebase 5.4.4?

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following tutorial for c++ from official website here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/password-auth#register_callback_on_future

Over there, it is mentioned that lambda captures are not supported as std::function is not supported by there compiler.
But, over here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/cpp-relnotes
in version 4.1.0 released in August 23, 2017 it is mentioned that they have added support for lambda captures.

When i write a function like this

```
void CreateUserInFirebase(const std::string& Email, const std::string& Password)
{
    auth->CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email.c_str(), Password.c_str());

    firebase::Future<firebase::auth::User*> Result = auth->CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordLastResult();

    Result.OnCompletion([&SomeVariable](const firebase::Future<firebase::auth::User*>& result, void* user_data)
    {}, nullptr);

}
```

It is giving this error

> error: no matching member function for call to 'OnCompletion'
>
> note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from lambda to 'firebase::Future::TypedCompletionCallback' (aka 'void (*)(const Future &, void *)') for 1st argument

Has the support been removed in latest version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnCompletion` has two overloads:

```
OnCompletion(TypedCompletionCallback callback, void *user_data) const
```

and

```
OnCompletion(std::function< void(const Future< ResultType > &)> callback) const
```

you defined lambda which takes two parameters, so compiler chooses first overload, but lambda captures `SomeVariable` - the code doesn't compile, lambda with capture cannot be converted to pointer to function.

If you want to call the second overload, your lambda should take only one parameter (`user_data` can be passed in capture list).

```
Result.OnCompletion([&SomeVariable](const firebase::Future<firebase::auth::User*>& result) {});
```

Comment: Thank you, rafix.
I am new to Firebase.
I did not know that 1st overload was using function pointer.
I will be using API reference too now while following the beginner guide.